# Получение FAT32 свойств файла

Tags: c++, fat32

Я хочу получить FAT32 свойства некоторого файла. Я уже разобрался как FAT32 хранит их и написал структуру для их хранения. Но возник вопрос: как их получить?

Сначала я хотел сделать так:

```
FILE* in = fopen("H:\\test.txt", "rb");
```

Но [`fopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) лишает нас этой информации.

Можно ли каким-либо образом получить FAT32 свойства файла?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С++ абстрагирует от вас свойства файловой системы, так что вам придётся пользоваться системно-специфическими функциями.

Для Windows информация, которая вам нужна, находится в структуре [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Её можно получить, например, при помощи [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Код из MSDN:

```
#include <windows.h>

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(filename, &FindFileData);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    // обработать ошибку
    return;
} 
else
{
    // можно пользоваться

    // не забудьте в конце:
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Для Linux-платформы аналогичную информацию выдаёт функция [stat (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sb;
if (stat(argv[1], &sb) == -1)
{
    // обработать ошибку
    return;
}
else
{
    // можно пользоваться
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Просто я пытался всё реализовать бегая по Fat таблице

Comment: Пожалуйста! Обратите внимание, этот код будет работать и на NTFS.

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов если вы хотите руками разбирать FAT/NTFS/прочее - CreateFile('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', ...) в винде.